# How to uninstall Amazon app in 17.10, 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, 17.10, uninstall, amazon

I do not particularly appreciate the Amazon logo reminding me to consume every time I open the app overview in Ubuntu 17.10 and later?

Since previous questions have been related to the Amazon launcher of the 17.10-irrelevant Unity-specific `unity-webapps-common` package, the answers are no longer applicable.

How may I in uninstall the app Ubuntu 17.10 running GNOME Shell?

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in `sudo dpkg -l`.

Comment: Those qeustions refer to Unity-based versions of Ubuntu and the answers do not work except to *hide* the launcher. I would like it properly gone.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-web-launchers
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you're bothered by its presence in app overview, you can simply go to `usr/share/applications` and remove the corresponding `.desktop` file (`ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop`) or add an extra `NoDisplay=true` line inside the `.desktop` file.